# Issue Installing scikit image in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, installation, scikit-image

I am having issues installing scikit-image for use with python3

I have it installed for python version 2.7 using pip install. I am now trying to install it in my folder for python3  and am getting this issue

> Obtaining file:///usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scikit-image
>   Collecting numpy>=1.11 (from scikit-image==0.14.dev0)
>     Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy>=1.11 (from scikit-image==0.14.dev0) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for numpy>=1.11 (from scikit-image==0.14.dev0)

I am navigating to the source folder and using

> sudo pip install -e .  as per the documentation. I have also tried sudo pip3 install -e . http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html

I am new to Ubuntu/programming so don't understand the issue; looking at the error it talks about numpy version 1.11. I do have this installed in my python3 folder so I don't understand the issue. The only way I have been able to install skimage for python3 is by using synaptic package manager, unfortunately, the only version available is version 0.10.1

Comment: Says that you need to update numpy to be at least 1.11

Comment: It is already 1.11 that's why I'm confused

Comment: How do you know it is?

Comment: Becuase when I run the command numpy.__version__ it gives me the output 1.11.0

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370583/pip-issue-installing-almost-any-library

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried running the suggested commands and the error was the same. I think the difference may be between pip and pip3? but I don't know. For some reason, the installation was fine when using pip into python 2.7, but now trying to install in python3 is a different beast.

Comment: no problemo! glad to help

Comment: Still no Luck getting this package in python3 I guess I will email the developer

Comment: try using a virtual environment which will basically create an isolated area for you to download packages.