# Cannot use pip to install packages, it reports an error on ssl certificate

Tags: python, openssl, pip

Just now I update the latest python and want to install packages through pip, but there raise a error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 45, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 62, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 775, in request
    headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 522, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)
```

I google this error and tried to update Openssl, but it does not work.
My Openssl version is `OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018`
My python version is `Python 2.7.14`
My pip version is `pip 9.0.1`

My ~/.base_profile is like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
```

someone said it is because some micro changes by shadowsocks, but it did not explain why and how to deal with it.

So what should I do to repair my pip and ssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798838/9586409.

You have to upgrade pip to a version with a TLSv1.2 support. You can do it by running this command:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!