# login page using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, wsgiref

I am using an  single page web application built on python 2.7 . I would need  to add a  simple authentication page  with username, password and login button  which will  redirect to the app.Also a logout button in the app page which will redirect to the  login page.  It  will  use  a single username  and password   that  will  be shared   with  users concerned.It uses wsgiref

```
from wsgiref import simple_server

from someApp import SomeAPI

app = SomeAPI()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    httpd = simple_server.make_server('0.0.0.0', 8000, app)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

I am trying to use  some middlware auth like falcon-auth or barrel . I get   the  error while  installing.

```
C:\Users\User1>pip install falcon-auth
Collecting falcon-auth
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning
```

I  finally  get the   error

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
```

What would a solution given that  I need  to use Python 2.7  and  not upgrade to a higher version

Comment: What happens when you update that library it says to upgrade?

Comment: I get the  error  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370583/pip-issue-installing-almost-any-library
would this help?