# Modules not installing/running properly

Tags: python-3.x

Every time I try to install a module through pip or otherwise, it doesn't install, and I just get an error when trying to import it.

when I try to run

`pip install Pillow`

(this happens with almost any module by the way, not just pillow)

I just get the following error message:

`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Pillow`

A similar issue also occurs when I try to run some previously installed modules, like Pygame and Matplotlib.
For the ones I had already installed, I tried deleting and redownloading, but when I tried to redownload, it gave the error message above.

Could it have something to do with the fact that I have 2.7 and 3.6 installed simultaneously?

I tried the solution suggested here, still same result. I don't know how the situation is different, it just is apparently
[pip issue installing almost any library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370583/pip-issue-installing-almost-any-library)

Comment: try using `pip3` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip issue installing almost any library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370583/pip-issue-installing-almost-any-library)