# How to trust host using pip 1.4.1

Tags: python, pip

I am stuck using pip 1.4.1 and have run up against a problem when upgrading package.

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymongo/: There was a problem confirming 
the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:509: error:1407742E:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version>
```

I have seen that later versions of pip you can do --trusted-host to ignore the certs warning. But on 1.4.1 it appears that this option is not available. How to fix?

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade pip? Which OS are you on? Did you check that you have the appropriate root certificates installed? Did it work before?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908406/3767239) help you?

Comment: Are you sure you have pip **1.4.1**? The most recent version is **20.0.2**. Your version would be more than ancient and outdated

Answer (score 0):

The worst problem in your case is not untrusted host, the worst problem is too old versions of Python and OpenSSL. Your `pip` tried to use protocol version TLS v1 which PyPI stopped supporting long ago.

To install packages over the Net you need to upgrade OpenSSL, Python and `pip`. If you cannot upgrade you cannot install from PyPI directly. Then you can try to download packages from PyPI using a browser and install them from the local filesystem.

You can also use `pip download` on a host with more modern OpenSSL/Python/`pip`, transfer downloaded packages to the ancient host and install them there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758