# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel python

Tags: python, macos, ssl, pip

Getting below error :

```
MacBook-Pro:$ pip install wheel
Collecting wheel
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/wheel/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wheel
MacBook-Pro:$ pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org wheel
Collecting wheel
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/wheel/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wheel
```

Try this no luck :

[pip issue installing almost any library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370583/pip-issue-installing-almost-any-library)
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5236

Using MacOs Sierra

```
MacBook-Pro:$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
MacBook-Pro:$ python -m pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Any help in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article help to solve my issue :
https://medium.com/@dipikabh/ssl-certificate-error-using-pip-install-154aa8e014fb

Steps mention there as  below :

1. Check the pip version before the upgrade (to verify the update later):

```
> MacBook-Pro:~ jane$ pip --version

> pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

2. Download get-pip.py

`> curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

3. Run the following command to upgrade pip:

`> MacBook-Pro:~ jane$ sudo python get-pip.py`

4. Verify the version of pip:

```
> MacBook-Pro:~ jane$ pip --version
> pip 20.1.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```