# Problems with installing selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, installation

I've been trying to install the selenium module in my coworker's computer and I haven't been successful. It occurs an error that I don't understand what's the problem.

The error message is in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiAEk.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908406/17845381) I think you should re-install/udpate pip. What OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this sir**

1. Uninstall the current Python installation.
2. As you are on Windows 7 professional OS use [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before the new installation of Python Client.
3. Download and install a new version of the compatible Python binary/executable.
4. Make sure you are using the latest version of pip.
   `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
5. Install latest version of Selenium:
   `pip install selenium`

I hope it works

Comment: In the step 4, am I supposed to do it in Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: yes you should, if in doubt read this https://datatofish.com/upgrade-pip-anaconda/