# Python 3.3 pandas, pip-3.3

Tags: python, pandas, pip

So, I'm trying to install pandas for Python 3.3 and have been having a really hard time- between Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 and other factors.

Some pertinent information:  I am running Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5.  I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 installed, but for my programming purposes only use 3.3.

This is where I'm at:  I explicitly installed `pip-3.3` and can now run that command to install things.  I have XCode installed, and have also installed the command line tools (from 'Preferences').  I have looked through a number of pages through Google as well as through this site and haven't had any luck getting pandas to download/download and install.

I have tried downloading the tarball, 'cd' into the downloaded file and running setup.py install, but to no avail.

I have downloaded and installed EPD Free, and then added 'Library/Framework/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH} to .bash_profile - still doesn't work.

I'm not sure where to go frome here...when I do `pip-3.3 install pandas` terminal relates that `There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:547)>` and so nothing ends up getting downloaded or installed, for either pandas, or I also tried to the same for numpy as I thought that could be a problem, but the same error was returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [pip github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/829) recommends:

> people to use a python that is linked to a more recent version of openssl.

*Apparently current versions of EPD Free do not, hence this error.*

[Lower down in the thread](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/829#issuecomment-17934156) ([and as a comment on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441224/can-i-relink-enthought-python-to-new-version-of-openssl-on-mac-os-x#comment21878764_15461901)) it's claimed that downgrading to pip version 1.2.1 should fix, e.g. via:

```
easy_install pip==1.2.1
```

Comment: thank you for this.  I was actually just trying this.  I do: `easy_install-3.3 pip-3.3==1.2.1` it does the downloading, etc and then returns this: `error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip-3.3: Permission denied`  ideas?

Comment: dur on my part!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I just had the same issue with Angstrom Linux on the BeagleBone Black board and the easy_install downgrade solution solved it.  One thing I did need to do, is after installing easy_install using

opkg install python-setuptools

I then had to go into the easy_install file (located in /usr/bin/easy_install)

and change the top line from #!/usr/bin/python-native/python to #!/usr/bin/python

this fixed easy_install so it would detect python on the BeagleBone and then I could run your solution.